# Ejecutar un comando cada 24 horas y 5 minutos con crontab

Tags: linux, crontab

Sé que para que se ejecute un comando cada 24 horas debe ser

```
0 7 * * * [comando]
```

Pero, por ejemplo, para que se ejecute cada 24 y 5 minutos ¿Hay manera de hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Pequeño error, aunque funciona.

```
0 7 * * * [comando]
```

Tu comando significa, a los cero minutos de la séptima hora diariamente. Osea, a las 7:00 de tu zona horaria.

Si lo que quieres es cada 24 horas y 5 minutos es.

```
5 */24 * * * [comando]
```

Eso lo puedes leer en `man 5 crontab`, que cada que quieras correr algo de la forma "cada x unidad" es algo de la forma

```
#unidades
#minuto  #hora  #dia  #mes  #dia de la semana
  */2     */2    */2   etc
```

Que significa que ejecutará un comando cada 2 minutos, cada 2 horas, cada 2 días, etc.

```
5 */24 * * * [comando]
```

Lo interpreta como, correr un comando pasando 5 minutos, cada 24 horas.

Ahora que si, como medio entiendo, quisieras algo a una hora específica, sería algo cercano a lo que pusiste.

```
5 7 * * * [comando]
```

Que entendería como la ejecución de esa tarea cada 7:05 de la zona horaria.