# Tarea Programada Centos

Tags: cron, jobs

tengo el siguiente script lo que hace es respaldar una carpeta en especifico en un lugar del pc y posterior a este subir a un servidor FTP lo cual funciona bien.

El problema es como puedo automatizar es decir que esto se ejecute  a las 19h00 cada dia , tengo sistema Operativo Centos 7, agradezco cualquier sugerencia, mi script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#fecha
day=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M")

#directorio a respaldar
directory="/root/Documentos/backup_Test"

#destino backup
archive_file="backupCodigo_$day.tgz"

destino="/root/Documentos/$archive_file"
tar -cvpzf $destino $directory

# CredencialesFTP (se puede especificar el puerto. ftp.ejemplo.com:2002)
ftpUser=miusuario_ft
ftpPass=mi_claveftp
ftpHost=ftp.mihost.com:21
ftpFolder="respaldoCodigo/"

echo "Subiendo el Archivo: $file al SeRvIdOr"
curl --ftp-create-dirs -T $destino -u $ftpUser:$ftpPass ftp://$ftpHost/$ftpFolder
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este tipo de preguntas ya tienen respuesta en:

[Ejecutar un comando cada 24 horas y 5 minutos con crontab](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225080/ejecutar-un-comando-cada-24-horas-y-5-minutos-con-crontab/225082#225082)

Pero retomando. El programa que necesitas se llama `crontab` el cual crea los archivos "crontab" de los usuarios.

Estos archivos son leídos y procesados por el demonio `cron` que ejecutará las tareas especificadas en cada archivo "crontab".

Estos archivos están almacenados según la distribución. Algunas veces en `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` en otros casos en `/var/spool/cron`.

Para crear tu archivo crontab, puedes usar el programa `crontab` con el parámetro `-e`, que permite editar, con el editor predeterminado, y luego instalar, el crontab del usuario en curso.

Una vez que útilizas `crontab -e`, te aparecerá un archivo de la forma.

```
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#   
# m h  dom mon dow   command
resto del archivo
...
```

En el cual tendrás que agregar la periodicidad de tu tarea a ejecutar y, de forma opcional, algunas variables de configuración para esas tareas programadas.

El formato de periodicidad lo puedes leer en `man crontab(5)`

```
campo               valores permitidos
-----               --------------
minuto              0-59
hora                0-23
dia del mes         1-31
mes                 1-12 (o nombres)
dia de la semana    0-7 (0 o 7 es Domingo, o usa nombres)
```

Es decir, si quieres una tarea programada para las 19 de cada día.

```
00 19 * * * <tu tarea>
# Al minuto 0, de la hora 19, cada dia del mes, cada mes, cada dia de la semana
```

puede ser tan simple o compleja como quieras.

Puede ser desde un simple script o incluso una condicional.

Por ejemplo.

```
00 19 * * * /root/respaldo.sh
00 19 * * * cd /root && ./respaldo.sh
00 19 * * * /bin/bash /root/respaldo.sh
00 19 * * * bash /root/respaldo.sh
00 19 * * * [ $(date -d +2day +\%d) -eq 1 ] && /root/respaldo.sh
00 19 * * * /root/respaldo.sh > /root/respaldo.log 2> /root/respaldo.error
```

Si a veces se pone la ruta completa del programa, por ejemplo `/usr/bin/python` o `/bin/bash` es porque para entender un comando como tal, `cron` tiene preconfigurado una variable PATH básica, la cual es `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`, eso lo puedes revisar en `man crontab(5)`, entonces a veces es bueno definir la ruta entera para no lidiar con que el programa que vas correr no se encuentre dentro de los directorios que se listan en la variable `PATH`. Otras opciones son definir una variable `PATH` en el mismo `crontab` o dentro del script o usar rutas absolutas a tus programas dentro de tu script.

Comment: gracias...genial..!!

Answer (score 0):

Escribe `crontab -e` para editar el archivo de `crontab` y agrega esta linea hasta abajo:

```
00 19 * * * /tu/path/script.sh
```

Si quieres que el script genere un log hazlo asi:

```
00 19 * * * /tu/path/script.sh >> /tu/path/script.log 2>&1
```